# Make PHPList the default mailing list in Plesk

Tags: plesk, mailing-list

How can I make PHPList the default mailing list manager (if possible) on Plesk 11? I've already added PHPList to the application vault from the application catalog. However, it isn't showing up as an available application in the Application tab for the subscriber. If it isn't possible to set it as default how I make it available as an application?

**UPDATE**

PHPList is showing up when one searches for it in the show all applications section of the applications tab. No headway on the default though.